# Flutter integration test failing with error `'_pendingFrame == null': is not true.`

Tags: flutter

I'm creating an integration test to my flutter app but I get this error when finding an `TextInput` and trying to type inside.
The error: `'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 1649 pos 12: '_pendingFrame == null': is not true.`

The code:

```
final Finder email = find.byWidgetPredicate(
      (widget) => widget is FutXTextField && widget.title == 'EMAIL',
    );

expect(email, findsOneWidget,
        reason: " Só pode haver um botão de escrever email");

await tester.enterText(email, "teste@teste.teste");
```

I didn`t find it anywhere on the internet what this error is.

Does anyone had this exception before and has any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: what flutter version do you use? I've encountered the same error and it's resolved by upgrading the Flutter to v3.0.4

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error when the app that I was running the test on threw an exception, if you check the logs do you see any errors occurring before your test failed?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error because of an **asynchronous method** that I used in my test but didn't `await`.